# Quick Sort code issue giving array out of bound exception

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

```
public class Solution {

    public static int partition(int []arr,int lb,int ub)
    {
        int start=lb;
        int end=ub;
        int pivot=arr[lb];
        while(start<end)
        {
            while(arr[start]<=pivot)
            {
                start++;
            }
            while(arr[end]>pivot)
            {
                end--;
            }
            if(start<end)
            {
                int temp=arr[start];
                arr[start]=arr[end];
                arr[end]=temp;
            }
        }
        int temp=arr[lb];
        arr[lb]=arr[end];
        arr[end]=temp;
        return end;
    }
    
    public static void quickSort(int[] input,int startIndex, int endIndex) {
        /* Your class should be named Solution
         * Don't write main().
         * Don't read input, it is passed as function argument.
         * No need to print or return the output.
         * Taking input and printing output is handled automatically.
         */
        if(startIndex<endIndex)
        {
            int loc=partition(input, startIndex, endIndex);
            quickSort(input,startIndex,loc-1);
            quickSort(input,loc+1,endIndex );
        }
    }
    
}
```

I have tried quick sort but out of 15 test cases 7 has been passsed and rest are giving ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.
Sample input is
302 401 679 712 389 377 259 605 553 467 357 998 294 369 913 932 859 324 282 161 879 344 205 988 356

Comment: Do not tag this as `dsa`.  The `dsa` tag is for `Digital Signature Algorithm`.

Comment: @Aayush Pachpande
I updated the answer, please check

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried quick sort but out of 15 test cases 7 has been passsed and rest are giving array out of bound exception

The reason is that the **start** and **end** pointers can both reach the end of the array in your code.

I changed your `partition` method code and fixed the issue:

```
public static int partition(int[] arr, int lb, int ub) {
    int start = lb;
    int end = ub;
    int pivot = arr[lb];
    while (start < end && start < arr.length && end >= 0) {
        while (start < arr.length && arr[start] <= pivot) {
            start++;
        }
        while (end >= 0 && arr[end] > pivot) {
            end--;
        }
        if (start < end) {
            int temp = arr[start];
            arr[start] = arr[end];
            arr[end] = temp;
        }
    }
    int temp = arr[lb];
    arr[lb] = arr[end];
    arr[end] = temp;
    return end;
}
```

Comment: `while (arr[start] <= pivot && start < arr.length)` - shouldn't that be `while (start < arr.length && arr[start] <= pivot)`? Otherwise, you could be checking `arr[start]` before you check if `start` is within valid bounds.